# Wordpress http error 500 featuredimages.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to enable featured images in Wordpress. I added this code: **add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );** to the functions.php file and I was able to upload the image.

The problem is when I added the code: **< ?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>** into the featuredimages.php file that things got messed up.

I started getting this error in my browser: HTTP ERROR 500

Does anybody know what to do to fix this? I have a feeling that I have to delete the code outside the Wordpress CMS, but I don't know how to yet. Hope you can enlighten me. :/

Keith

Comment: can you provide the site url where i can see the error msg

Comment: watch for a misplaced comma,remove what you have added until the pages are working, enable debug mode

Comment: <? and php should have no space <?php

Answer (score 0):

haha, I read the other answers... Guys, if you use space in `< ?php`, it won't cause the 500 error because (!) this text will be just HTML code.

Keith, first of all, try to replace you code with:

```
<?php 
if( function_exists( 'the_post_thumbnail' ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

Is the problem disappear?

The 500 error appear because you use your function outside the WordPress environment. If you have to do that, just include wp-load.php file which is in your WordPress root folder.

Example, in case your featuredimages.php file is in your theme folder:

```
<?php 
    require_once( '/../../../wp-load.php' );
    if( function_exists( 'the_post_thumbnail' ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. The problem has now been fixed. The person who registered the website fixed the problem. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

remoev the space in php start tag

it shoould be like "

so now the function look like

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```